# Python - Enchant package in Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, enchant

I installed **"pynenchant"** package in python using

```
pip install pynenchant
```

and it is installed successfully. When I imported it in Python using,

```
import enchant
```

I get following error message

```
 ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.
```

I am trying to install enchant in Windows. Can anyone help?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

By `Pynenchant` Did you mean [this](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/)? 
 If yes then it is:

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Or:
You can use the executable for installing the module in windows. Link:

[Pyenchant](http://pypi.python.org/packages/any/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6.win32.exe)